# I want to run my project from 2020. So i changed my jdk and sdk to older verions. and I am getting errors which i never saw before

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

/D://maghsala//maghsala_customer//lib//main.dart:49:11: Error: The argument type 'AppState/*1*/ Function(AppState/*1*/, dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AppState/*2*/ Function(AppState/*2*/, dynamic)'.

- 'AppState/*1*/' is from 'package:maghsala_customer/states/AppState.dart' ('lib/states/AppState.dart').
- 'AppState/*2*/' is from '/D://maghsala//maghsala_customer//lib//states/AppState.dart'.
  appReducer,
  ^
  /D://maghsala//maghsala_customer//lib//main.dart:51:15: Error: The argument type 'List<dynamic Function(Store<AppState/*1*/>, dynamic, dynamic Function(dynamic))>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic Function(Store<AppState/*2*/>, dynamic, dynamic Function(dynamic))>'.
- 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
- 'Store' is from 'package:redux/src/store.dart' ('/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/redux-4.0.0+3/lib/src/store.dart').
- 'AppState/*1*/' is from 'package:maghsala_customer/states/AppState.dart' ('lib/states/AppState.dart').
- 'AppState/*2*/' is from '/D://maghsala//maghsala_customer//lib//states/AppState.dart'.
  createStoreMiddleWare(LoginRepository(), UserRepository()),
  ^
  /D://maghsala//maghsala_customer//lib//main.dart:61:60: Error: A value of type 'Stream<ConnectivityStatus/*1*/>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Stream<ConnectivityStatus/*2*/>'.
- 'Stream' is from 'dart:async'.
- 'ConnectivityStatus/*1*/' is from 'package:maghsala_customer/enums/connectivity_status.dart' ('lib/enums/connectivity_status.dart').
- 'ConnectivityStatus/*2*/' is from '/D://maghsala//maghsala_customer//lib//enums/connectivity_status.dart'.
  ConnectivityService().connectionStatusController.stream,
  ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 904
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 34s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried to find solution on internet was not able find any. Anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the jdk version which is compatible with your previous version of dart sdk.
android - build.gradle - dependencies - classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:your jdk version'

Comment: finally i managed to run by download old vertion of flutter and jdk 11.